# Random or Fixed Effects

Tags: hausman

I am analysing purchasing behaviour using a negative binomial regression. I observe different products over several days, products differ in their popularity, there is no observable characteristic for that, therefore I would like to use a random or fixed model. I tried to find a solution by conducting hausman tests. Here I wonder whether to include all variables (controls) or only my time variant variables. If i include only my time variant variables hausman shows p>chi2 = 0,075. What would you recommend for this situation? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly model it using [Linear Mixed Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model)

A commonly used test for such nested models is to determine if including a fixed effect or random effect is significant is the [Likelihood Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test) which uses a Chi-square test too.

An example using the `lme4` package in R and `MixedLM` in `statsmodels` is [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/saketkc/statsmodels/blob/kerby_mixedlm_notebooks/examples/notebooks/Mixed_Linear_Models.ipynb)